# Does the following define a continuous stochastic process on $[0,1]$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{A}, P)$ be a probability space and let $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{R})$ denote the measurable space defined by the real line with its Borel $\sigma$-field. Now, let the map $X:(\Omega,\mathscr{A})\mapsto(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{R})$ define a random variable with Gaussian distribution.

Let $f\in C$, with $C\equiv C[0,1]$ denoting the space of continuous functions on the closed unit interval. Equipe $C$ with the uniform metric and let $\mathscr{C}$ denote the Borel $\sigma$-field generated by the open subsets.

Introduce the map on $Y:\omega\mapsto X(\omega)f$, for every $\omega\in\Omega$. Does this map define a (measurable) random element of $(C,\mathscr{C})$?

My question is maybe a trivial one. Yet, should the distribution of $X$ have been  supported on a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$, I would have said "yes". In this case, it is not clear to me what the answer should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you expect that the distribution plays a role at all? In order to talk about measurability, we don't even need a probability measure!

Denote by $I(t) := 1$, $t \in [0,1]$, the mapping which is constantly $1$ and define

$$\Omega \ni \omega  \mapsto T(\omega) := X(\omega) I \in C[0,1].$$

Let's show that $T$ is measurable. Fix some $g \in C[0,1]$ and $\epsilon>0$. Note that for any constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$, we have

$$\begin{align*} c \cdot I \in B[g,\epsilon] &\stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} \forall t \in [0,1]: |g(t)-c| \leq \epsilon \\ &\iff \forall t \in [0,1]: g(t)-\epsilon \leq c \leq g(t)+\epsilon \\ &\iff c \in \left[ \max_{t \in [0,1]} g(t)-\epsilon, \min_{t \in [0,1]} g(t)+\epsilon \right] =:U \end{align*}$$

As $U$ is an interval (possibly empty), it is clearly a Borel set. Consequently, we find by the measurability of $X$ that

$$T^{-1}(B(g,\epsilon)) = \{X \in U\} \in \mathcal{A}.$$

As $g \in C[0,1]$ and $\epsilon>0$ are arbitrary, this shows that $T$ is measurable. Since the mapping

$$\Omega \ni \omega \mapsto f \in C[0,1]$$

is trivially measurable (for $f$ fixed), we find that

$$\Omega \ni \omega \mapsto X(\omega) f$$

is measurable as the product of two measurable mappings.

Comment: Let me try to express my doubt in a clearer way. Obviously, $C[0,1]$ is a subset of $\ell^\infty[0,1]$, the class of bounded functions on $[0,1]$. Now, given my definition of $X$, there is no positive real $M$ s.t. $P(\vert X \vert \leq M)=1$. In this view, given your definition of $T$, how could you guarantee that $P\{\omega: T(\omega) \in C[0,1]\}=1$ since there is no positive real $M'$ s.t. $P\{ \omega: \Vert T(\omega) \Vert_\infty \leq M' \}=1$? Am I missing something?

Comment: @JackLondon Well, you are confusing some things. $T(\omega) \in C[0,1]$ means that for any **fixed** $\omega \in \Omega$ the image $T(\omega)$ is a continuous mapping on $[0,1]$ (in particular bounded). The constant mapping $$(T(\omega))(t) = X(\omega), \qquad t \in [0,1]$$ is clearly continuous, in particular $$\sup_{t \in [0,1]} |(T(\omega))(t)| \leq |X(\omega)|<\infty.$$